User creation only by admin and teacher using devise
I'm developing an app to a horsemanship school with class booking. But, right now I'm a bit stuck, because I need the app to only allow the admin and teachers to create a new user (the students and athletes who attend the classes as well as new teachers that might be signed in the future).
I'm using Ruby on Rails and Devise and already tried to use a solution from this thread, and I'm still getting the alert that the user is already logged in.
Can anyone give me some lights on what I have to do?
Thanks in advance!

This is not a feature built into Devise.  The registrations controller is only designed to handle user signing up themselves. You can lock the registrations down by skipping the new and create routes and then create your own UsersController which is essentially the same as any other controller. Alternatively you can use the Devise Invitable gem to let admins invite the users, this provides a way to handle passwords automatically.

Thanks max. I also need a password generator, so Devise Invitable probably is the best way to go, right?

Yeah, it does what it says on the tin.
